# Inkskape Object>Clip>Set

Tags: inkscape

Can U help me?

I have a problem with the Clip function. I have a large .PNG but I need only part of this file, so I use the Clip function, but I understand that Inkscape holding in memory full images, this is makes work hard. Do you know a solution? How can I keep only the part which I need???

Answer (score 1):

You could crop the image smaller in a raster image editor such as GIMP, by using the crop tool. Then select all, and copy it, and then paste it into Inkscape.

If the image is still too large, you can reduce its size in GIMP by doing *Image > Scale Image*, and reduce the number of pixels. This will also reduce the resolution, so perhaps don't make it too small.

Sometimes PNG images can have quite large file sizes, so you may wish to export as a JPEG instead from GIMP, then import the JPEG into Inkscape. Note however that JPEGs do not support transparency.

Sometimes, if you don't want to use another editor, it's possible in Inkscape to resize a raster image using a bit of a hack. You can put it in a rectangular clipping mask to kind of crop it, then scale it down, and then make a raster copy using *Edit > Make Bitmap Copy* - then delete the original raster image.  However, that's quite a lot of steps, and a real raster image editor will make a much better job of the resizing.  Inkscape is a vector image editor and has very limited raster editing capabilities.